# How to get random mongodb documents using aggregate() and $sample?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, fastify

I am trying to get 2 random documents within a collection called 'templates' but I only get an Internal Server Error.

I have successfully tested the following code in the mongo shell:

```
    db.templates.aggregate([{"$sample":{"size":2}}])
```

Could there be a problem with the `fastify` syntax?

```js
    module.exports = async fastify => {
      fastify.get(
        '/',
        {
          schema: {
            response: {
              200: {
                type: 'object',
                items: {
                  type: 'object',
                  properties: {
                    _id: {
                      type: 'string'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        async (req, res) => {
          try {
            const result = this.mongo.db
              .collection('templates')
              .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 2 } }])
            return await result
          } catch (err) {
            res.internalServerError()
          }
        }
      )
    }

    module.exports.autoPrefix = '/questions'
```

I am getting an Internal Server Error, expecting 2 random documents.

Comment: could you please print the error from you catch block?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the handler of your route.

If you use arrow function the `this` is the upper scope, instead if you use a simple function `this` will bind to the fastify instance.

So you should change to:

```js
async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const result = this.mongo.db // this will work as expected
      .collection('templates')
      .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 2 } }])
      .toArray()
    return await result
  } catch (err) {
    res.internalServerError()
  }
}
```

Otherwise remove the `this`:

```js
async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = fastify.mongo.db
      .collection('templates')
      .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 2 } }])
    return await result
  } catch (err) {
    res.internalServerError()
  }
}
```